# "Apply Now" email button in header doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

1. Open vacancy that accepts applications via email (example: [this job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/116080/teamwork-projects-software-developer-teamworkcom))
2. Scroll down until original header will be replaced with vacancy-specific navigation
3. Click "Apply now" button in header

**Actual result:** Nothing happens

**Expected result:** Popover should appear as if we click on the same button in the body

Tested in Chrome 60.0.3112.101 and in Firefox 54.0.1

[image: apply now bug preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.

We changed a CSS class, but we forgot to update the relevant Javascript. Derp.

Thank you for your report!